# Environment variable not recognized

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

Win 7 Ultimate.  .NET Core, SDK 2.1, Web MVC project.

config.json

```
{
  "Colors": {
    "Favorite": "blue"
  },
  "DisableSSL": false,     
  "ConnectionStrings": {...
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  }    
}
```

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddMvc(opt => { if (env.IsProduction() && config["DisableSSL"] != "true")
      { opt.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); } }) 
    .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings
      .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

When I publish to a folder and open a CLI in the folder and `set DisableSSl=true` and run the app from the CLI and then browse to `localhost:5000` I'm redirected to https://localhost.

Why is the `DisableSSL` from the CLI not overriding the one in the config file?

If I comment out the `.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());` and republish and run from the CLI it doesn't redirect and I can navigate to the website at localhost:5000 so the publish is working properly.

I know how to create a certificate to run under SSL, that is not my question.

How do I get it to recognize the environment variable set in the CLI session?

(If create an `Environment Variable` under `System Properties` `DisableSSL` with value `true`.  It is also ignored and I'm redirected).

Answer (score 1):

So I have ran a test and perhaps I have found your problem:

Take the following `appsettings`:

```
{
  "Test1": true,
  "Test2": "true",
}
```

Now let's take a look at what we get:

```
var one = Configuration["Test1"];
//result: one == "True"
var two = Configuration["Test2"];
//result: two == "true"
```

So when you sest the Environment variable to true, I am assuming it brings it up as "True" and due to case sensitivity `"True" != "true"`. Try converting it to lower case.

Comment: Everything is already lowercase.  Your test only confirms that what I'm doing should work.  I test for "true" and in the environment set DisableSSL=true.

Comment: @Joe are you using Powershell or CMD to set the env variable?

Comment: CMD.  Doing from Powershell still redirects.

Comment: @Joe did you try `$Env:DisableSSL = "true"` in powershell?

Comment: Still redirects.